# Magento wishlist view.phtml not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.13

I am trying to edit the wishlist page layout table, and was sure i was able to do so in the template/wishlist/view.phtml file, but nothing happens. I have been trying to locate the file to edit, but i cant seem to find it. The wishlist module is the Mage enterprise module, default in magento.

How do i edit the wishlist page table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the template files Magento loads, you can enable **Template Path Hints**.

1. Go to **System > Configuration > Developer**
2. At the top left, change the **Current Configuration Scope** to your *Website View* (the second option in the list)
3. Now expand the **Debug** section and set **Template Path Hints** to `Yes`.
4. Click **Save Config** and flush your Magento caches.

Now when you load the Wishlist pages, you will see the template file path of the top of the section you are referring to.