# Call an extension template in a static block magento

Tags: magento

I have used a testimonial Magento extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-testimonial-manager.html

How to call any extension in a static block?  How to find the block path and name?

Comment: i want to display the testimonial box in homepage. so i need to call it in a staic block. how to do this?

Comment: See my updated answer to find block path and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static blocks can be included in CMS page by:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="my_block" template="cms/content.phtml"}}
```

Non-static block can be called in cms page by:

```
{{block type="" template="block template"}}
```

For "type" in "{{block }}" part refer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633307/understanding-magento-block-and-block-type)

You can find the block by enabling enabling "Template Path Hints" as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098472/magento-wishlist-view-phtml-not-working)